# C# Socket.Send( ): does it send all data or not?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I was reading about sockets from a book called "C# Network Programming" by Richard Blum.  The following excerpt states that the Send() method is not guaranteed to send all the data passed to it.

> ```
> byte[] data = new byte[1024];
> int sent = socket.Send(data);
> ```
>
> On the basis of this code, you might be tempted to presume that the
>   entire 1024-byte data buffer was sent to the remote device... but this
>   might be a bad assumption.  Depending on the size of the internal TCP
>   buffer and how much data is being transferred, it is possible that not
>   all the data supplied to the Send() mehtod was actually sent.

However, when I went and looked at the Microsoft documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w93yy28a(v=vs.110).aspx it says:

> If you are using a connection-oriented protocol, Send will block until
>   all of the bytes in the buffer are sent, unless a time-out was set

So which is it?  The book was published in 2004, so has it changed since then?

I'm planning to use asynchronous sockets, so my next question is, would BeginSend() send all data?

Comment: Didn't you see in the doco - _"[**Returns:** The number of bytes sent to the Socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w93yy28a(v=vs.110).aspx)"_

Comment: @Micky: Ignoring the documentation in favor of black box observations is a spectacularly bad idea which leads to code that fails on other computers, after a Windows update, or even when your computer happens to have more or fewer threads ready to run simultaneously.

Comment: @BenVoigt Perhaps.  But then again, the Documentation forms a contract and if behaviour is dependent on the environment then the Documentation should say so

Comment: @MickyD: Indeed the documentation forms a contract.  All environments are required to abide by that contract.  Some environments may do more, but the documentation *isn't* required to elaborate on anything above and beyond the contract.

Comment: @BenVoigt ok thanks buddy

Answer (score 2):

All you had to do was read the rest of the exact same paragraph you quoted.  There's even an exception to your quote given in the very same sentence.

> If you are using a connection-oriented protocol, Send will block until all of the bytes in the buffer are sent, unless a time-out was set by using Socket.SendTimeout. If the time-out value was exceeded, the Send call will throw a SocketException. **In nonblocking mode, Send may complete successfully even if it sends less than the number of bytes in the buffer. It is your application's responsibility to keep track of the number of bytes sent and to retry the operation until the application sends the bytes in the buffer.**

For `BeginSend`, the behavior is also described:

> Your callback method should invoke the EndSend method. When your application calls BeginSend, the system will use a separate thread to execute the specified callback method, and **will block on EndSend until the Socket sends the number of bytes requested or throws an exception**.

That's not a very nice design and defeats the whole point of a callback!  Consider using [`SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync(v=vs.110).aspx) instead (and then you still need to check the `BytesTransferred` property).

Answer (score 0):

Both of the resources you quoted are correct. I think the wording could have been better though.
Inthe docs, [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.send?view=netframework-4.7.1) it is also written that

> There is also no guarantee that the data you send will appear on the
>   network immediately. To increase network efficiency, the underlying
>   system may delay transmission until a significant amount of outgoing
>   data is collected.

So `Send` method is blocking until underlying system has had room to buffer your data for a network send.

> A successful completion of the Send method means that the underlying
>   system has had room to buffer your data for a network send.